# Angular js : convert date to another timezone

Tags: angularjs, date, timezone, converters

I have to convert my date to different timezone based on the logged user timezone

I have tried

```
$scope.currentDate = Date.now();
$scope.tz = 'America/New_York';
```

In view i have called like this `{{currentDate | date:'h:mm a' : t}}`

But it's not working.,..how could i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [`Moment timezone JS`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var now = moment(new Date());
  $scope.currentDate = now.tz('America/New_York').format('hh:mm a');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.4/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app'>
  <div ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <h4>{{ currentDate }}
</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm getting timezone as string only not get offset

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy

**In HTML Template Binding**

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

**In JavaScript**

```
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)
```

Comment: {{currentDate | date:'h:mm a' : 'America/New_York'}} Not working ..its showing local time only

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
{{currentDate | date:'h:mm a' : '+500'}}
```

otherwise make a filter to format date which will use moment to format in any format and timezone  as following:

```
inputFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
moment(input, inputFormat).format(outputFormat)
```